# Unit Testing Angular HttpInterceptor: toHaveBeenCalledWith apears never called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I am unit testing a little error-handling interceptor and I want to test that a certain function has been called with arguments. The toHaveBeenCalledWith function gives a "but it was never called" in the console. Does anyone have an idea why this is the case? The other tests seem to work.

Error.interceptor.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    let errorMsg = '';
    if (error.status === HTTP_STATUS_ABORTED) {
      errorMsg = 'An client-side or network error occurred';
    } else if (error.status === HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {
      errorMsg = 'An internal server error occurred';
    } else {
      errorMsg = `Backend returned code ${error.status}`;
    }

    console.error(errorMsg, ', body was: ', error.error);

    // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
    return throwError(() => {
      return new Error(errorMsg);
      // return error;
    });
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}
```

Error.interceptor.spec.ts:

```
describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
  let client: HttpClient;
  let httpController: HttpTestingController;
  let interceptor: ErrorInterceptor;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        ErrorInterceptor,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    });

    client = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(ErrorInterceptor);
    spyOn(console, 'error');
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call handleError with the correct errorObject on code 400', () => {
    spyOn(interceptor, 'handleError').and.callThrough();

    const expectedErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
      url: '/target',
      status: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
      error: new ProgressEvent('ERROR', {}),
    });

    client.get('/target').subscribe({
      error: (error: Error) => {
        expect(error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(error).toEqual(new Error('Backend returned code 400'));

        expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          'Backend returned code 400',
          ', body was: ',
          expectedErrorResponse.error
        );

        expect(interceptor.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          expectedErrorResponse
        );
      },
    });

    const httpRequest: HttpRequest<any> = new HttpRequest('GET', '/target');
    const err = new ProgressEvent('ERROR', {});

    httpController.expectOne(httpRequest).error(err, {
      status: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpController.verify();
  });
});
```

I tried to test whether the interceptor calls the handleError function.
I expected the `expect(interceptor.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedErrorResponse);` to test that it calls the function and return a truthy expect.

EDIT: The fix found by Jonas Ruth:

-> Call done in the subscribe block of the test

```
  it('should call handleError with the correct errorObject on code 400', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const spyOnHandleError = spyOn(
      interceptor,
      'handleError'
    ).and.callThrough();

    const expectedErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
      url: '/target',
      status: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
      error: new ProgressEvent('ERROR', {}),
    });

    client.get('/target').subscribe({
      next: (returnValue) => {
        fail(`Expected error but got "${returnValue}"`);
      },

      error: (error: Error) => {
        expect(error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(error).toEqual(new Error('Backend returned code 400'));

        expect(interceptor.handleError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          expectedErrorResponse
        );

        done();
      },

      complete: () => fail('Complete must not be called'),
    });

    const httpRequest: HttpRequest<any> = new HttpRequest('GET', '/target');
    const err = new ProgressEvent('ERROR', {});

    httpController.expectOne(httpRequest).error(err, {
      status: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
    });
  });
```

Providers: make sure the instance is the same

```
  ErrorInterceptor, // instance A
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useExisting: ErrorInterceptor, // instance A (will use the same instance)
    multi: true,
  },
],
```

->  error.interceptor.ts.

````
.pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)));```
````

Comment: can you add `fakeAsync` at the beginning of your tests ? Since you use `subscribe`, your test is not synchronous anymore.

Comment: Look this [Angular Guide - Testing Services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services)... There are some examples that will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried with fakeAsync and also using done(), but it gives the same expect turning to false. The code does reach the subscribe block. Any other things I can try out? I also checked the angular guide, thanks for that!! However, If I mock the http with a spy it will not use the interceptor anymore, so I don't know what to do to get my test working.

Comment: Here is [the doc](https://angular.io/guide/http-test-requests) again ;)

Answer (score 1):

After investigating considerably I came up with a solution to your problem.

The interceptor instance being spied is not the same instance that Angular is using.

```js
// error.interceptor.ts

providers: [
  ErrorInterceptor, // instance A (the instance spied)
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor, // instance B (another instance used by Angular)
    multi: true,
  },
],
```

So you need to change `useClass` to `useExisting` in the providers config:

```js
// error.interceptor.ts

providers: [
  ErrorInterceptor, // instance A
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useExisting: ErrorInterceptor, // instance A (will use the same instance)
    multi: true,
  },
],
```

Now the error response expectation will be called, but the spied `handleError` method will receive two values from [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) that corresponds to `error` and `caught` because `handleError` was declared the following way in the `intercept` method. So the expectation will not match and fail.

```
// error.interceptor.ts

.pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
```

Output (with comment):

```
Expected spy handleError to have been called with:
          [ HttpErrorResponse({ headers: HttpHeaders({ normalizedNames: Map(  ), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(  ) }), status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: '/target', ok: false, name: 'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for /target: 400 Bad Request', error: [object ProgressEvent] }) ]
        but actual calls were:
          [ 
            HttpErrorResponse({ headers: HttpHeaders({ normalizedNames: Map(  ), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(  ) }), status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: '/target', ok: false, name: 'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for /target: 400 Bad Request', error: [object ProgressEvent] }), 
            // below observable was not expected
            Observable({ source: Observable({ _subscribe: Function }), operator: Function }) 
         ].
```

I suggest two options as a solution to match the error response expectation:

(1) you can change the way you are passing the `handleError` method to something like the following code:

```
// error.interceptor.ts

.pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)));
```

(2) Or change how the spy and expectation is declared but keeping its equivalence:

```
// error.interceptor.spec.ts

// add spy into a variable to further use
const spyOnHandleError = spyOn(interceptor, 'handleError').and.callThrough();
```

```
// error.interceptor.spec.ts

// break the error response expectation into two expectations
// that use spyOnHandleError to get some useful information

// expect to be called
expect(spyOnHandleError.calls.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);

// expect the most recent call first argument to match the `expectedErrorResponse`  
expect(spyOnHandleError.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toEqual(expectedErrorResponse);
```

With these changes your test will run successfully!

Final output:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Chrome 113.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.033 secs / 0.021 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

**Completely updated answer**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I added these to the code, but sadly that doesn't fix the problem yet, still getting the same assert to false. I also tried the fakeAsync method in there, but that also doesn't change anything. Any other things I can try out?

Comment: Your tests passed here after two small changes. I completely updated my answer with the positive result!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was away for a while. Thanks so much!! It works! Learning a lot from this!